# Find element index in an array in Perl 6

Tags: raku

How can I find the index of an element within an array?

For example, given

```
my @weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
```

How could I find the index for `'Thursday'`?

Comment: Awesome! In cases like this, you can post both a question and an answer at the same time.

Comment: yes. I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

My initial solution:

```
@weekdays.kv.reverse.hash.{'Thursday'} # 3
```

Then [JFerrero](https://twitter.com/JFerrero) posted his improvement solution using **[antipairs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/antipairs)**:

```
@weekdays.antipairs.hash.{'Thursday'} # 3
```

And [ultimatto](https://twitter.com/ultimatto) posted an **[adverb](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#index-entry-subscript_adverb_%3Ak-%3Ak)** solution:

```
@weekdays.first('Thursday', :k)  # 3
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`first`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/first) (or `grep`, if you want to know about all matches, not just the first one) with `:k` to return the key (which for a list is always an Integer index) instead of the value:

```
say @weekdays.first('Tuesday', :k);  # 1
```